# Can not choose chrome browser on Cypress

Tags: cypress

On cypress IDE I can't choose another browser except than 'Electron'. I would like to choose Chrome browser. Before it was possible to choose. But now it is impossible. How can I fix issue?
Thanks in advance for your help

[image]

Comment: Do you have chrome installed on your machine?

Comment: @AlapanDas, Yes chrome installed on my local machine.

Comment: Can you try running the command `npx cypress open --browser chrome`.

Comment: Can't run because you've entered an invalid browser name.

Browser: 'chrome' was not found on your system or is not supported by Cypress.

Cypress supports the following browsers:

chrome
chromium
edge
electron
firefox
You can also use a custom browser: https://on.cypress.io/customize-browsers

Available browsers found on your system are:

electron

Comment: But chrome already installed on my machine

Comment: You can check these threads - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3645 | https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6334 | https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2834 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731593/cypress-5-0-unable-to-find-installed-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official documentation "Cypress automatically detects available browsers on your OS" (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Browsers).

On linux, I would also recommend to use .deb files to install the browsers, using flatpak didn't work for me.

Windows and macos is the same, just make sure to have it installed.

I would also recommend checking the following:

- [Cypress 5.0 - Unable to find installed browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731593/cypress-5-0-unable-to-find-installed-browsers)
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2834
- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Common-GitHub-issues

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was (macOS) that chrome was installed, but the name of the app in /Applications was 'Google Chrome 2'
I renamed it so it has no '2'in the file name and it's ok now