# No browser option displayed to select in Cypress tool dropdown even if the browsers are installed in local machine

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cypress

I have installed Cypress version: 9.1.0, and I see only ELectron Browser as the default browser in the tool.
I have Google Chrome version 96.0 and Firefox installed in my local system but Cypress is unable to detect it. As I need to run the test on cross-browser only the Electron browser is displayed.

I tried to solve this issue as suggested in: [Cypress 5.0 - Unable to find installed browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731593/cypress-5-0-unable-to-find-installed-browsers)

But still unable to resolve the issue and only Electron browser is shown in the tool as shown below:
[image]

when I tried to run the command `npx cypress run --browser chrome` it shows below error

[image]

I also tried running the command `npx cypress open --browser "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`
but got the below error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have chrome browser installed on your local machine?

Comment: Yes it's installed with version: 96.0